# Increase Ubuntu 16.04 partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I few weeks ago I gave a try to Ubuntu 16.04, I installed it alongside Windows with about 20GB of storage.

However, now I'm running out of space, can't get rid of Windows and I'm very new in this.

I have read a lot of posts regarding this same question but for every case there is a different solution. And I don't want to mess things up.

So here is a screenshot of GParted (I installed it)

[image: Gparted]

`/dev/sd4` is where windows is installed.

What do I have to do?

What if a create another unallocated partition from windows, how can I add it to the Ubuntu partition?

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that sure but the best way to partition is to run gparted from a DVD-disk or a flash drive running lubuntu (because it's lightweight) or something else that has gparted included or is installable. From there you can run gparted by typing on the commandline `sudo gparted`. It opens a gparted window and from there you can resize, delete and add partitions without interfering with the program partioning so you can unmount all.